# Aplicar formula a distintos indices de distintas listas en Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

Hola a todos estoy llevando a cabo un proyecto personal, para realizar cálculos y obtener un output que me sirva de input para otro programa, pero me he visto envuelto en un serie de dudas, es decir, estoy intentando realizar operaciones como las que se hacen en Excel, pero en Python, he conseguido obtener un resultado, pero estoy atascado en la iteración.

A qui va la cuestión:

Después de leer un archivo .hdf5, obtengo una serie de datos y los guardo como listas, de tal manera que tengo:

```
listaA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,.......,100]
# La lista A es mas corta que las otras tres listas
listaB = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,.......,10000]
listaC = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,.......,10000]
listaD = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,.......,10000]
```

Una vez tengo mis datos en 4 listas, creo la cabecera de salida.

```
# Cadenas fijas
cabecera = '  Res   A     B      C       D \n'
unidades = '   m   (m)   (m)    (m)     (m)\n'
```

Como necesito operar sobre las 4 listas, las uno con zip.

```
listaUnion = []
for union in zip(listaA,listaB,listaC,listaC):
    listaUnion.append(union)
```

Imprimiendo esto obtengo una lista unión de las 4 anteriores, hasta alcanzar la ongitud de la listaA.

```
[(1,1,1,1),(2,2,2,2),(3,3,3,3),.....(100,100,100,100)]
```

realizo la operación que necesito con:

```
resultado = []
for i in range(0, len(listaA):
    opA =1000-(math.log(listaA[5][0]/listaA[4][0]))+(listB[5][1]+listaB[4][1])))
    print(round(opA,4))
    resultado.append(opA)
```

En principio esto hace lo siguiente, selecciona el elemento 5 de la lista A y lo divide entre el elemento 4 de la lista A, luego suma el elemento 5 de la lista B con el elemento 4 de la lista B, pero esto solo me da un valor, es decir, me da un resultado para los elementos seleccionados, aqui está el problema, no consigo hacer que se realice la operación sobre los elementos siguientes, tendría que ir al elemento 6 de la lista A y dividirlo entre el elemento 5 de la lista A y con la suma de igual manera,
así hasta llegar al ultimo valor de la lista A.
Por último guardo el resultado de la operación en otra lista y lo uno a las demás listas:

```
final = []
for k in zip(resultado, listA, listaB, listaC, listaD):
    final.append(k)
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado esperado,me dice que la operación no se puede realizar, por lo que intuyo que estoy accediendo mal a los indices.
Es pero me puedan ayudar u orientar de como puedo seguir.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no me queda claro exáctamente qué cálculo quieres hacer.

- ¿Qué rango de la lista quieres recorrer? Porque en tu ejemplo haces referencia a la posición 5 pero tu iteración recorre la lista listaA entera.
- Las operaciones en cada lista de división, suma, etc  del ejemplo, ¿se han de hacer a dos elementos consecutivos?
- Si las operaciones en cada iteración se hacen en dos elementos consecutivos, ¿a qué fila se le asignara ese resultado, a la primera o a la segunda?

A parte, además de algún error de sintaxis,

```
for i in range(0, len(listaA)):
```

en tu código accedes a las listas `listaA` y `listaB` con 2 índices

```
opA =1000-(math.log(listaA[5][0]/listaA[4][0]))+(listB[5][1]+listaB[4][1])))
```

cuando son listas de enteros, lo que significa que estás intentando acceder a un entero con un índice, lo que te debería dar un `TypeError`.

Con todo esto, y suponiendo que las operaciones en cada iteración se hacen para dos elementos consecutivos de las listas `listaA` y `listaB`, que se recorre todo el rango de la `listaA` y que tu lista de resultados tiene un elemento menos que la lista A, tu iteración podría quedar así:

```
resultado = []
for i in range(1, len(listaA)):
    opA =1000-(math.log(listaA[1]/listaA[i - 1]))+(listaB[i]+listaB[i - 1])))
    print(round(opA,4))
    resultado.append(opA)
```

---

### UPDATE:

Con la aclaración de que el resultado es acumulativo, y siendo `formula()` el resultado de los cálculos en cada iteración, el bucle anterior podría ser algo así:

```
resultado = []
opA = 1000 # Valor inicial
for i in range(len(listaA)):
    opA -= formula()
    resultado.append(opA)
```

Ten en cuenta que la expresión `opA -= formula()` equivale a `opA = opA - formula()`

Comment: Hola Jon, se me estropeo el ordenador, acabo de ver tu respuesta y he visto donde estaba mi error, solo me queda una duda, la formula empieza en 1000 - ( formula ), pero el problema está en que el siguiente valor debe ser el resultado anterior - ( formula).

Comment: ¿Y no podrías por ejemplo, inicializar la variable `opA=1000` antes del bucle, e ir sumando o restando el resultado de la fórmula en cada iteración?

`opA += (fórmula)`

De esta forma el resultado en cada iteración sería el valor inicial (1000) más el acumulado de todas las iteraciones anteriores. Si no, creo que sigo sin entender exactamente qué necesitas...

Comment: Se supone que debería hacer lo siguiente,    opA = 1000 - formula    , esto supongamos que da [800], pues el siguiente resultado tendría que ser [opA = 800 - formula], esto supongamos que da 300 , el siguiente seria [opA = 300 - formula] y así hasta que acabe la lista, y  los resultados los guardaría en una lista.

Comment: Actualizo respuesta

Comment: perfecto!!!, gracias Jon.

Comment: Me ha surgido una duda, respecto al bucle principal, veo que el bucle ejecuta hasta alcanzar la longitud de la lista A, (100 valores), pero las listas B, C, D, tienen 10.000 valores, por lo que me surge una duda, la operación empieza en 1000, recorre los 100 elementos y para, pero como se podría hacer que volviera a empezar en 1000 e hiciera la operación con los siguientes valores de las listas B, C, D?, porqué si en el bucle principal modifico la longitud de la lista hace un acumulativo hasta alcanzar el final de la lista, pero esto no sería correcto.